# bootstrap button is not working with jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery form plug-in for posting my form ajax way.
Post is working fine with default button.But it is not working when I am using custom bootstrap button as below . Please let me know what i am missing here?

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#validation

**Working case :**

```
<input name="Update" value="Update" type="submit">
```

**Not working case:**

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-bitbucket" name="Update" value="Update" type="submit">
                                        <i class="demo-icon icon-ccw fa-fw" style="font-size:1.3em;"> </i> Update
</a>
```

Comment: Great Kieran !!! It worked !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just removed my comment as any of these should work:

```
<input name="Update" value="Update" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-bitbucket">

<button class="btn btn-sm btn-bitbucket" name="Update" type="submit">
    <i class="demo-icon icon-ccw fa-fw" style="font-size:1.3em;"></i> Update
</button>
```

An anchor can't (by default) be used to submit the form, hence why it isn't working. However Bootstrap allows you to use the button classes on `input` and `button` tags.

*Sorry for the ghost comment now!*